# Android GridView cell sequence changing

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I'm getting a very odd (to me) issue when populating a GridView - when it first loads all looks fine, but scrolling ends up with data from cells moving to other positions. In the following example I just have an ArrayList of the numbers 0-800, and an 8 column grid. When loaded 0-7 is in the first row, 8-15 in the second etc, with a different value in the first cell in each row. But after scrolling the first column value will change. Here's the code - it's driving me crazy!

MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<800;i++) {
        positions.add(i);
    }

    GridView gvVals = findViewById(R.id.gvVals);
    CellAdapter adapter = new CellAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Integer>());
    adapter = new CellAdapter(this, positions);
    gvVals.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Cell Adapter.java:

```
public class CellAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {
private Context context;
public CellAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> vals) {
    super(context, 0, vals);
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v;
    if (convertView == null) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_cell, parent, false);
    } else {
        v = (View)convertView;
    }

    TextView tvDay = v.findViewById(R.id.tvVal);
    tvDay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if(position % 8 == 0) {
        tvDay.setText("ST:"+position);
    }
    else
    {
        v.findViewById(R.id.btnM).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnM)).setText(position + " ");
        tvDay.setText(" ");
    }
    return v;
}
```

ActivityMain.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gvVals"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:numColumns="8"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

ActivityCell.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvVal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnM"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".34"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="M"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

GridView when app first opened

[image: GridView when app first opened]

After scrolling down a few rows and then back up

[image: After scrolling down a few rows and then back up]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

> ```
> TextView tvDay = v.findViewById(R.id.tvVal);
> tvDay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>
> if(position % 8 == 0) {
>     tvDay.setText("ST:"+position);
> }
> else
> {
>     v.findViewById(R.id.btnM).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
>     ((Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnM)).setText(position + " ");
>     tvDay.setText(" ");
> }
> ```

to this:

```
boolean firstColumn = position % 8 == 0;

TextView tvDay = v.findViewById(R.id.tvVal);
tvDay.setVisibility(firstColumn ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

Button btnM = v.findViewById(R.id.btnM);
btnM.setVisibility(firstColumn ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);

if(firstColumn) {
    tvDay.setText("ST:"+position);
}
else
{
    btnM.setText(position + " ");
}
```

It's important when working with RecyclerView to make sure that you always update every view every time. This is because old view holders get recycled, so if you only do something some of the time, it can get overwritten or it can overwrite the "expected" behavior.

Previously, you were making `btnM` visible if it wasn't the first column, but you weren't making it not visible if it **was** the first column.

Comment: Thankyou so much, this has been annoying me for days!